# Why does Spring Boot take so long to find method handler

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I have a service configured using Spring Boot and Swagger.

My swagger paths config look like this:

```
paths:
  /hello/test:
    post:
      summary: Hello World Test
      description: >-
        Hello World
      operationId: helloTest
      tags:
        - Hello
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/HelloRequest'
        description: Hello Request
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: >
            OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/HelloResponse'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'
        '401':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unauthorized'
        '403':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Forbidden'
        '500':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/InternalServerError'

  /confirmations:
    post:
      summary: Hello World Confirmation
      description: >-
        Hello World Confirmation
      operationId: postConfirmations
      tags:
        - Confirmation
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConfirmationRequest'
        description: Hello Confirmation Request
        required: true
      responses:
        '204':
          description: >
            No Content
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'
        '403':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Forbidden'
        '500':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/InternalServerError'
```

My logs keep showing this message several times

```
Did not find handler method for [/hello/test]
```

Even after this message is shown:

```
Returning handler method [public default org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.sample.hello.generated.emvco.model.HelloResponse> com.sample.hello.generated.emvco.api.HelloApi.postTransactionCredentials(com.sample.hello.generated.emvco.model.HelloRequest)]
```

This takes up to 5 milliseconds of initial resolution which impacts the performance of the service. What causes spring to look repeatedly for one path which is clearly defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think such a problem mainly comes when the **structure of the project** is not in the right way. I assume your controller class is **not found or taking time** during scanning cause it is in a package that will not be scanned by default. I guess your application is not in the right way or default structure. please change your controller to com.app.controller and check performance.